# How to pass parameter as class not as string to New-Object?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-3.0

I can't seem to pass $outputStream as Stream to StreamWritter constructor. It gets passed as string and then it invokes wrong constructor that expects string not stream.

```
$tcpClient = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient        
$connect = $tcpClient.BeginConnect("localhost", 8080, $null, $null)
$success = $connect.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne($testTimeoutMs, $true)
[System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream]$outputStream = $tcpClient.GetStream()
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList $outputStream, [System.Text.Encoding].ASCII
```

I want to invnoke this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3aadshsx(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor but it invokes one with string parameters instead of Stream.

This results in this error:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Maciej\System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream' because it is being used by anothe
r process."
At line:1 char:12
+  $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList $outputStr ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

**How to force to pass this parameter as Stream not as string?**

Comment: Tried again explicite referencing the typ [System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream]$outputStream as argument?

Comment: @dsdel Yes. It just treated that type as part os string.

Comment: $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $outputStream, [System.Text.Encoding].ASCII - skip the -ArgumentList - at least local in a quick test no error came up

Comment: I did test the code posted in the Q and the first attempt worked, the following attempts didn't work (same error "the process ..." ) - if I close the powershell window and open a new one, it works again.

Comment: It works for me using `[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII` not `[System.Text.Encoding].ASCII`. (Notice the `::`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is trying to access the `[Encoding]` class's static member with the wrong syntax:

```
[Text.Encoding].ASCII
```

In PowerShell, you access type static members with the following syntax:

```
[Text.Encoding]::ASCII
```

This object has the type `[System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]` according to `.GetType()` which inherits from `[System.Text.Encoding]` and should resolve the [constructor errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) you're receiving:

```
$tcpClient = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient'

$connect = $tcpClient.BeginConnect('localhost', 8080, $Null, $Null)
$success = $connect.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne($testTimeoutMs, $True)

$outputStream = $tcpClient.GetStream()
$writer = New-Object -TypeName 'System.IO.StreamWriter' -ArgumentList @($outputStream, [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)
```

As a side-note, in v5+, you can natively call the constructor method:

```
$streamWriter = [IO.StreamWriter]::new($outputStream, [Text.Encoding]::ASCII)
```